# I have a problem when I use fetch in nativescript-vue

Tags: nativescript, fetch-api, nativescript-vue

When I do a fetch request to ("http://localhost:5000/api")
I get this error:

> [TypeError: Network request failed: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.]

This is my code I use for trying to fetch the data but I get that error all the time. What is the best way to fix this or is it any other solution to use for fetching and posting data in Nativescript?

```
methods: {
      getData() {
       fetch("http://localhost:5000/api")
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
       }).catch((err) => {
     console.log(err)
   });

 },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Http is not enabled by default in iOS and Android (v9.0 and above).

To enable Http requests on iOS, you will have to add the following keys to your `App_Resources/iOS/info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

On Android, you will have to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your `application` tag of your `App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication" 
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

You may also allow Http communication only on specific domains, refer official iOS / Android docs for more information.